# htaccess - CSS not loading when URL doesn't end with /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have .htaccess file placed at `example.com/new` directory. I want to rewrite every URL from `example.com/new/it/keyword` to `example.com/new/index.php?lang=it&keyword=keyword`. My current `.htaccess` is this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+) index.php?lang=$1&keyword=$2 [L]
```

The problem is that `example.com/new/it/keyword/` works fine, but `example.com/new/it/keyword` does not load CSS and images, it loads only HTML. How should I fix it?

Comment: Use absolute paths to your style sheets and other assets in your HTML pages. `/path/to/css/styles.css`

Comment: can it be fixed through `.htaccess` only?

Comment: In theory yes, by building a RewriteRule that makes style sheets available in every rewritten directory á la `/new/it/keyword/css` but that’s awful on many levels, e.g. there’s no caching style sheets because to the user’s browser, each will be a different resource. it’s really much better to use proper paths.

Comment: @Pekka웃 great, so I replaced every URL in HTML from "img.png" to "/img.png" and it's working now, thanks. You can make it an answer

Comment: You’re welcome. I added an answer, although this has many many duplicates that are easily found even when Googling `htaccess - CSS not loading when URL doesn't end with /` - in the future, don’t forget to search first!

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths to your style sheets and other assets in your HTML pages, like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/css/styles.css">
```